# understanding the definition of domains of holomorphy

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

can anyone give me an example and explain why any open set in $\mathbb{C}$ is a domain of holomorphy?

I have understood the fact from here but not able to understand their explanation for $n=1$

Comment: where is 'here'? And who are 'they'?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_holomorphy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear that $\mathbb{C}$ itself is a domain of holomorphy.

For other domains, let $p$ be a boundary point of $\Omega$ and put $$f(z) = \frac{1}{z-p}.$$ Then $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ (indeed on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ p \}$) and can't be extended across $p$.